# Guide on how to install FreeBSD on a laptop

Tags: freebsd

Is there a guide on how to install FreeBSD on a Laptop with some basic GUI elements or a Desktop Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/) is the canonical reference to learn how to install and administer a FreeBSD system. Different areas are covered, from server administration to graphical window systems.

Comment: Thank you I had not seen that this the updated handbook. The hardware list I had seen was pretty old. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out [PC-BSD](http://pcbsd.org) which simplifies the installation for you and also comes with it's own [Documentation](http://www.pcbsd.org/en/documentation/). It is based on FreeBSD and comes with the KDE destop manager by default. This would be recommended for the casual pc user, but if you want the learning experience, then I would recommend going with rahmu's answer. Ensure the laptop meets the hardware requirements, if you are unsure you can always try a live CD first. Have fun!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I downloaded it just in case :)

Comment: No problem, hope you find it as useful and fantastic as I did